# Can't detect image height jquery

Tags: jquery, height, size

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $(".zoom").hover(function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 0.7
            }, "fast");
        },
        function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 0},
            "fast");
        });
        });

    function resizeElements() {
        // find out the width of the page
        var img_width = $(".img-effect, .wp-post-image").width();
        var img_height = $(".img-effect").height();

        // apply the new width to the middle column
        $('.zoom, .caption').css('width', img_width);
        $('.zoom').css('height', img_height);
    }

    $(window).resize(resizeElements);

});

var img_width = $(".img-effect").width();
var img_height = $(".img-effect").height();
$('.zoom').css('width', img_width);
$('.zoom').css('height', img_height);
```

Could you please help me with the code above. When I alert `img_width` it shows me the picture width, but when it comes to `img_height` it results in 0. Image appears normally. The funny thing is that on resize it detect height fine.

Answer (score 3):

There's a high chance that the images aren't loaded yet on document ready. Use the window load event instead. The window load event is fired when all images are fully loaded and visible. See http://api.jquery.com/load-event/.

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var img_width = $(".img-effect").width();
    var img_height = $(".img-effect").height();

    alert(img_height);
});
```

Comment: That makes sense, because resizeElements is called later, after window load.